# Why doesn't contextmanager reraise exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace class's `__enter__`/`__exit__` functions with single function decorated as `contextlib.contextmanager`, here's code:

```
class Test:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._cm_obj = self._cm()
        self._cm_obj.__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        try:
            # Here we first time caught exception,
            # Pass it to _cm:
            self._cm_obj.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
        except:
            # Here we should catch exception reraised by _cm,
            # but it doesn't happen.
            raise
        else:
            return True

    @contextmanager
    def _cm(self):
        print('enter')
        try:
            yield
        except:
            # Here we got exception from __exit__
            # Reraise it to tell __exit__ it should be raised.
            raise
        finally:
            print('exit')


with Test():
    raise Exception(123)
```

When we got exception inside Test's `__exit__`, we pass it to `_cm`'s `__exit__`, it works fine, I see exception inside `_cm`. But then, when I decide to reraise inside `_cm`, it doesn't happen: after Test's `__exit__` I don't see exception (and code works wrong, without exception).

Why doesn't exeprion reraised inside `__exit__`?

If it's normal behavior, could you advice me solution to properly replace `__enter__`/`__exit__` with `contextmanager` function?

**Edit:**

`cm_obj.__exit__` returns `None` on exception inside `_cm` and `True` if exception was suppressed (or not raised at all).

At other side, inside `Test.__exit__` we can return `None` to propagate current exception or `True` to suppress it.

Looks like just returning `cm_obj.__exit__`'s value inside `Test.__exit__`do job, this code working as I want:

```
class Test:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._cm_obj = self._cm()
        self._cm_obj.__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self._cm_obj.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

    @contextmanager
    def _cm(self):
        print('---- enter')
        try:
            yield
        except:
            raise  # comment to suppess exception
            pass
        finally:
            print('---- exit')


with Test():
    raise Exception(123)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is not *raised* in `__exit__`, so there is nothing to *re*raise.

The exception is passed in to the method as arguments, because you can't raise an exception in another method (other than a generator). You don't have to raise the exception either, you need to simply return *not* return a true value for the exception to be propagated. Returning `None` should suffice.

From the [*With Statement Context Managers* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__):

> Exit the runtime context related to this object. The parameters describe the exception that caused the context to be exited. If the context was exited without an exception, all three arguments will be `None`.
>
> If an exception is supplied, and the method wishes to suppress the exception (i.e., prevent it from being propagated), it should return a true value. Otherwise, the exception will be processed normally upon exit from this method.
>
> **Note that `__exit__()` methods should not reraise the passed-in exception; this is the caller’s responsibility.**

Bold emphasis mine.

You instead suppress the result of the `self._cm_obj.__exit__()` call, and return `True` to ensure the exception isn't raised again:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self._cm_obj.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
    return True
```

If you didn't return `True` here you'd see the exception re-raised by the `with` statement.

You can't re-raise exceptions that don't reach the context manager however. If you catch and handle an exception in the code block (inside `_cm` for example), then the context manager will never be told about this. Suppressed exceptions *stay* suppressed.

Note that `@contextmanager` can't change these rules; although it transfers the exception into the generator with `generator.throw()`, it also has to catch that same exception if your generator doesn't handle it. It'll instead return a false value at that moment, because *that is what a `contextmanager.__exit__()` method should do*.

Comment: "return True to ensure the exception isn't raised again" - in that case every exception would be suppressed, but I want it to be suppressed only if it was suppressed inside _cm() and to be reraised if it wasn't suppressed inside _cm()

Comment: @germn: you can't. Suppressed exceptions in the block do not reach the context manager.

Comment: "you can't raise an exception in another method (other than a generator)" - which is one of the reasons `@contextmanager` wants you to give it a generator.

Comment: @user2357112: yes, the exception is sent back with `generator.throw()`. But `contextmanager.__exit__` is not a generator so the exception in the managed context is not raised in it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I edited post. Couldn't you check, am I wrote everything right?

Comment: @germn: yes, returning the result of `self._cm.__exit__()` means you are wrapping the context manager correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When a context manager's `__exit__` method needs to indicate that an exception should be propagated, it does not do so by propagating the exception out of `__exit__`. It does so by returning a falsy value.

`@contextmanager` provides a different API to you, but it still needs to convert that to the normal context manager API to show to Python. When the exception passed to a `@contextmanager` context manager's `__exit__` is propagated out of the wrapped function uncaught, `@contextmanager` catches the exception and returns a falsy value from `__exit__`. That means that this call:

```
self._cm_obj.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

does not raise an exception, because it's caught by `@contextmanager`.

You can see the code where `@contextmanager` catches the exception in [`Lib/contextlib.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/contextlib.py#l34)

```
            try:
                self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
                raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
            except StopIteration, exc:
                # Suppress the exception *unless* it's the same exception that
                # was passed to throw().  This prevents a StopIteration
                # raised inside the "with" statement from being suppressed
                return exc is not value
            except:
                # only re-raise if it's *not* the exception that was
                # passed to throw(), because __exit__() must not raise
                # an exception unless __exit__() itself failed.  But throw()
                # has to raise the exception to signal propagation, so this
                # fixes the impedance mismatch between the throw() protocol
                # and the __exit__() protocol.
                #
                if sys.exc_info()[1] is not value:
                    raise
```